# Inheriting a packed C struct

Tags: c++, data-structures, struct

I am using a third party library (mavlink) that defines a number of structs that are all tagged with `__attribute__((packed))` so they can be efficiently be transmitted across a serial connection (it is written in C and I am using it in a C++ application).  When I receive and reconstruct them I would like to add a time stamp field to them.  I think the simplest way is to create a new struct that inherits the existing struct.  i.e. in the mavlink library this struct is defined:

```
MAVPACKED(
typedef struct __mavlink_heartbeat_t {
 uint32_t custom_mode; 
 uint8_t type; 
 uint8_t autopilot; 
 uint8_t base_mode; 
 uint8_t system_status;
 uint8_t mavlink_version; 
}) mavlink_heartbeat_t;
```

where `MAVPACKED` is a macro that applies `__attribute__((packed))`. `sizeof(mavlink_heartbeat_t)` returns 9.  If I define

```
    struct new_heartbeat_t : mavlink_heartbeat_t
    {
        uint64_t timestamp;
    };
```

`sizeof(new_heartbeat_t)` returns 24, so it looks like 7 padding bytes are added (I would assume to end of mavlink_heartbeat_t so that timestamp start at byte 16.)

Are there any gotchas or things to be aware of when doing this or is there a better way?

Comment: encapsulation might be more maintainable in the long run.

Comment: You can try to apply attribute__((__packed)) attribute on your structure and check the size.

Comment: @RichardHodges how do you mean? Do you mean instead of inheriting `mavlink_heartbeat_t` making it a private member of the new struct and then providing accessors to each of the members of `mavlink_heartbeat_t`?

Comment: @manu - if I do that, the size does shrink to 17 bytes but I'm not really concerned about that since this point the data is received and won't be transmitted over a serial line again.

Answer (score 0):

Inheritance is a *is a kind of* relationship.

Is the local representation of a heartbeat really *a kind of* wire message? I doubt it.

But it might reasonably *contain* one.

I would encapsulate it something like this:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstddef>


typedef struct __attribute__((packed))  __mavlink_heartbeat_t {
 uint32_t custom_mode; 
 uint8_t type; 
 uint8_t autopilot; 
 uint8_t base_mode; 
 uint8_t system_status;
 uint8_t mavlink_version; 
} mavlink_heartbeat_t;


extern std::uint64_t now();
void sync_fetch_data(mavlink_heartbeat_t&);
void foo(uint8_t);

struct local_heartbeat
{

  mavlink_heartbeat_t const& get_io_buffer() const {
    return io_buffer_;
  }

  mavlink_heartbeat_t& prepare_receive() {
    request_timestamp_ = now();
    return io_buffer_;
  }

  void complete_receive() {
    response_timestamp_ = now();
  }


  std::uint64_t get_response_timestamp() const {
    return response_timestamp_;
  }

private:
  // stuff in here might have suspect alignment
  mavlink_heartbeat_t io_buffer_;

  // but these will be aligned for optimal performance
  std::uint64_t request_timestamp_;
  std::uint64_t response_timestamp_;
};



int main()
{

  // create my local representation
  local_heartbeat hb;

  // prepare it to receive data
  auto& buffer = hb.prepare_receive();

  // somehow populate the buffer
  sync_fetch_data(buffer);  // could be async, etc

  // notify the object that reception is complete
  hb.complete_receive();

  // now use the local representation
  foo(hb.get_io_buffer().system_status);

}
```